# Setting stdout from awk as input for "if"

Tags: if-statement, stdout

As part of my script I need to search through some files, and check if the value of a certain column is equal or greater to a given number.

In this simplified example I want to see if the value in column 3 of the first line is greater than 10:

```
head -1 examplefile | awk '{print $3}' | if [?? > 10 ]; then print "YES"; fi
```

The problem is to call on stdout from awk (which is then the number I want) as input for the if command (??).

Should be simple enough, but I guess I'm just stupid... ;)

Cheers, 
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set the output of `awk` to a variable ?

```
myVar=$(head ... awk '{print $3}')
```

and test that in the `if` statement.

```
if [ $myVar -gt 10 ]; then
    print "YES"
fi
```

(I think you'll need the `-gt` [operator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)).

Or why not use [awk's conditional statements](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/awk-conditional-statements/) and avoid this altogether ?

Comment: Thanks! Setting it to a variable solves the problem, so now I only have to put this into the for-loop so that it will function in the script...